# Preventing higher order array methods from throwing an error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to prevent errors from being thrown while filtering?

The below function sometimes fails at `conversationMember.Name.toLowerCase()` when there is no conversationMember.

If it helps, this is also a computed property in a Vue application.
Should you need more information, please just ask!

```
filteredConversations() {
    var self = this;
    var filteredConvos = self.conversations;

    filteredConvos = filteredConvos.filter(conversation => {
        return conversation.MembershipData.some(conversationMember => {
            return conversationMember.Name.toLowerCase().includes(
                self.conversationSearchTerm.toLowerCase()
            );
        });
    });

    return filteredConvos;
},
```

Comment: You could check if that array is empty before you try to access the property. Or you could do a try catch around it, but if you don't intend to do anything with that error that would be bad practice.

Comment: Btw is `conversationMember` an array or an object? Because how would you access the `Name` attribute on an array?

Comment: `conversationMember` is an object. I will correct my error in my question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with arrays.

From your code I understand `conversationMember.Name` is supposed to be a `string` (because you're calling `.toLowerCase()` on it), which means `incudes` here is not `Array.prototype.includes`, but [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), especially since `self.conversationSearchTerm` seems to also be a string (you're also calling `.toLowerCase()` on it).

So, the problem is you're using `includes` on something that should be a `string` but is not. The simple fix is to default it to an empty string when it's falsy:

```
return (conversationMember.Name || '').toLowerCase().includes(
  (self.conversationSearchTerm || '').toLowerCase()
);
```

As a side note, you don't need the `var self = this;`. `this` is available inside your filter since the filter is an arrow function. So your function (I'm guessing it's a `computed` but it can as well be a `method`) could look like this:

```
filteredConversations() {
  return this.conversations.filter(c => 
    c.MembershipData.some(md => 
      (md.Name || '').toLowerCase().includes(
        (this.conversationSearchTerm || '').toLowerCase()
      )
    )
  );
}
```

One last note: this will still fail if any of your `conversations` does not have a `MembershipData` holding an array. To get around that, you could default it to an empty array on the fly:

```
 ...
   (c.MembershipData || []).some(md => 
 ...
```

As expected, any conversation without an array in `MembershipData` will be filtered out by the function (not included in the result) - because `.some(condition)` will return false when called on an empty array.